# How to change DocumentRoot to a custom folder

Tags: linux, apache, centos

I got my new VPS server with CentOS 5.8, I could not transfer my domain yet but I want to reach my site  via `http://my-server-ip` and since I am using laravel framework I need to change default DocumentRoot `httpdocs` to `httpdocs/public` I have tried to put those lines to httpd.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost my-server-ip:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/my.domain.org/httpdocs/public
ServerName  my.domain.org
</VirtualHost>
```

However after restarting apache it warns me like this:
Warning: DocumentRoot [/public] does not exist

What should I do?

Comment: Does the folder actually exist and does it have the proper permissions for access by Apache?

Comment: oops. this is my first day on linux :/ how can I give permission to Apache? (the folder oes exist) (post it as answer so if it works, I can accept it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to enable read (and possibly execute) privileges on the directory. As root try:

```
# Recursively set the owner of this folder to 'www'
chown -R www /var/www/vhosts/my.domain.org/httpdocs/public

# Recursively give the owner read and execute privileges
chmod -R u+rx /var/www/vhosts/my.domain.org/httpdocs/public
```

As an alternative on some setups the user might be called `nobody`. So if `www` doesn't work try:

```
chown -R nobody /var/www/vhosts/my.domain.org/httpdocs/public
```

EDIT:
As user [tink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1394729/tink) pointed out in the comments
*"...in Centos the user running apache is aptly called `apache`. In debian and it's derivatives, it's `www-data`."*

Comment: Did not work and I observed something weird: I saw TAB button completes directory names,  "cd /var/www/vh "tab" pla "tab" htt "tab"  However; it does not complete public although I can reach that folder

Comment: Well ... in Centos the user running apache is aptly called apache.  In debian and it's derivatives, it's www-data.  That may be the cause of your problem?

Comment: he can start with all as the most general and then, once he gets it to work, narrow down the permissioning to the strictest functional level

Comment: foampile, I think that's poor advice, really. Most people in my experience will leave it at what they perceive as a working solution, and not bother w/ then tightening perms up.

Comment: i said "once he gets it to work, narrow down the permissioning to the strictest functional level".  he has to start somewhere and the wide ballpark is better than shooting for the bulls eye and missing due to low prob.  once in the ballpark, he narrows down.  your rigid attitude for right vs. wrong offers little perspective.

Comment: @tink Thanks for the info. I'm updating the answer to include the other possible names for the Apache user.

Answer (score 0):

might be that the apache user can't get into the new directory.  try

`chmod a+r /var/www/vhosts/my.domain.org/httpdocs/public`

Comment: As an alternative it's probably better practice just to give read + execute permissions to the Apache user (normally `nobody` or `www`).

Comment: Ok, I am real linux noob (trying to learn it), where does this command specify that the privilege will be given to Apache user?

Comment: See my answer. The main difference is this method gives read access to the directory to any user which is probably unnecessary. I highly recommend checking out the chmod manpage or one of the various online tutorials for understanding linux file permissions. You can access it using the command `man chmod`.

Comment: some combination of chmod and chown is likely to ultimately work, he really needs to play around and try different things, depending on his configuration

Comment: @HasanAyan -- when you specify a+r, that means add read (+r) to all users on the system.  similarly, g+w would mean add write to users from the same group associated with the file/dir, o+r means add read to other (non owner or non group etc).  like Michael said, read the chmod man page

Comment: Ok I have solved it (there was a stupid error)
No errors but apparently my documentroot did not change :/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same "403 page" problem. Just after I changed Document Root in my /etc/apache2/conf-available/sitename.conf from /var/www/html to /data/www.
To solve the problem I did the folowing:

1) Utilized chown and chmod examples, provided by Mike (2 posts above). Many thanks to him;

2) Added 2 lines to the end of /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/web-data as follows:

```
/data/www/ r,
/data/www/** r,
```

and then run:

```
sudo service apparmor reload
```

3) I also needed to add the following bit of code to my apache.conf:

```
<Directory /data/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

May be some actions were superfluous, but It worked pretty nice for me (Apache v2.4.7,  Ubuntu 14.04.1)